# Dojo Calendar MatrixView

Tags: dojo, calendar

Trying to get this widget to render in a basic way.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/eca/resources/dojox/calendar/themes/tundra/MatrixView.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/eca/resources/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/eca/resources/dojox/calendar/themes/tundra/Calendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/eca/resources/styles/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/eca/resources/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/eca/resources/dijit/themes/dijit.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/eca/resources/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/eca/resources/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/eca/resources/styles/standard.css">
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/eca/resources/images/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/eca/resources/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/eca/resources/spring/Spring.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/eca/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" type="text/javascript">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

....
matrixView  = new MatrixView({
 style: "position:relative;width:900px;height:600px;"
}, "courseInstanceCalendar");
....
```

I have excluded dojo code before and after for simplicity.

What I'm getting now is only rows with week number and columns with day name like the screenshot but no grid with date values like this [example](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/calendar/tests/matrixview.html).

Any idea what's missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing this style fixed the problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/eca/resources/styles/standard.css">
```

So now I have a calendar that looks like the [example](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/calendar/tests/matrixview.html).

The lesson learned I guess is when you have rendering problems like this always check clashing styles.